# Set extremely small font size in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to reduce the font size to extremely small scale? for eg. in the range of 0.001pt or even small.

Comment: Why don't you use the simple `px` unit?

Comment: Have you tried? What would be the point of that anyway?

Comment: In my particular application I just need to have extremely small font size. ie.to use with svg. I could reduce it upto 0.0006rem, when I reduce the last digit by 1, it simply disappears

Comment: When you reduce the size of the font smaller than one pixel, it disappears because it's physically impossible for the monitor to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. As per my understanding, it is not possible to reduce font size up to that scale. By saying 'not possible', I mean there will be any further reduction in size after 1px.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, you can use rem for example:

```
font-size: 0.01rem;
```

See a CodePen here: https://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/VyJPxq

Comment: your codePen resulting font-size is 6px. you need to set the body{font-size: 1px;} for example to make the p-tag smaller then 1px. Furthermore an important information is missing: it is possible to make the "value" of the rule smaller then 1px. BUT: monitors can´t display  it. So whatever you want to achieve, should be possible to achieve differently.

Comment: It is simply disappearing on further reduction

Answer (score 0):

Just try it out i would say:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="font-size:0.001pt;">
The content of the body element is displayed in your browser.
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry I need further small

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use px

```
font-size: 5px;
```

Or whatever value you want...